# Query regarding Artifactory APIs

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to integrate with **Artifactory** using rest APIs and to do that need to be able to do the following:

1. Give a filter list of repositories based on tool type e.g I will like to only get repositories which are either `nuget` or `npm` based. I tried using https://user.jfrog.io/user/api/repositories but it doesn't return the type of repository so i cannot filter the list.  I see that https://user.jfrog.io/user/api/storageinfo returns `repositoriesSummaryList` which includes the package type of repositories. Is it ok to use this APIs for getting the list of repositories and filtering?
2. Given a repository I want to get list of packages in that repository. The only way i could find out for this was making a **POST** call to https://user.jfrog.io/user/api/search/aql with the body

   ```
    items.find( 
    { 
      "repo":{"$eq":"myawesome-remotenugetrepo-cache"} 
    } 
   )
   ```

   Is there any way to get this information using a **GET** call instead of **POST**?
3. In **Artifactory** different versions of same package are treated as different packages For Example: For the Query in 2 the result is something like this:

   ```
      [  
       {  
       "repo": "myawesome-remotenugetrepo-cache",  
       "path": ".",  
       "name": "bootstrap.3.3.2.nupkg",  
       "type": "file",  
       "size": 264693,  
       "created": "2016-05-27T16:07:12.138Z",  
       "created_by": "admin",  
       "modified": "2015-12-03T12:57:47.000Z",  
       "modified_by": "admin",  
       "updated": "2016-05-27T16:07:12.166Z"  
     },  
     {  
       "repo": "myawesome-remotenugetrepo-cache",  
       "path": ".",  
       "name": "bootstrap.3.3.6.nupkg",  
       "type": "file",  
       "size": 290372,  
       "created": "2016-05-27T10:55:47.576Z",  
       "created_by": "admin",  
       "modified": "2015-12-03T12:57:48.000Z",  
       "modified_by": "admin",  
       "updated": "2016-05-27T10:55:47.613Z"  
     },  
     {  
       "repo": "myawesome-remotenugetrepo-cache",  
       "path": ".",  
       "name": "jQuery.1.9.1.nupkg",  
       "type": "file",  
       "size": 240271,  
       "created": "2016-05-27T10:55:43.895Z",  
       "created_by": "admin",  
       "modified": "2015-12-07T15:58:51.000Z",  
       "modified_by": "admin",  
       "updated": "2016-05-27T10:55:43.930Z"  
     }  
   ]
   ```

As you can see the result includes entries for both versions of **bootstrap 3.3.2** and **3.3.6**. What I hoped was that the list of packages will just include **bootstrap** and **jQuery**, Is there anyway to get this list? 
Also give the package bootstrap is there any way to query for different versions of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. You can use the [Folder Info GET request](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FolderInfo).
3. There are two questions there :)

   1. Not really. You'll probably have to write a simple script to group by the common part of the artifact name.
   2. You can get information about the version of the artifact once you have a [repository layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) set up. Then you can use queries like [Artifact Version Search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactVersionSearch).